# How to Pass ID to JQuery URL in Laravel Blade

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I have a js file that generates a chartjs chart. I want the chart to pull data dynamically using an 'id'.

This is the code in Laravel Blade:

```
<div class="card">                      
  <canvas id="dash-donut-rice" width="100%" height="100%"></canvas>
  <script src="{{url( 'vendor/dash-donut.js' )}}"></script>
</div>
```

Here is the Route:

```
Route::get('/get-donut/{id}', 'DashboardController@getDonut');
```

Here is the Controller:

```
public function getDonut($id)
    {
        //dd($id);
        $new = PurchaseOrder::where('status', 'NEW')->where('bu_id', $id)->count();
        $completed = PurchaseOrder::where('status', 'COMPLETED')->where('bu_id', $id)->count();
        $cancelled = PurchaseOrder::where('status', 'CANCELLED')->where('bu_id', $id)->count();

        $total = PurchaseOrder::where('bu_id', $id)->count();
        //$center_text = ($completed / $total) * 100 . '%';
        if ($total == 0) {
            $center_text = '0%';
        } else {
            $center_text = number_format(($completed / $total) * 100, 0) . '%';
        }

        $donut_data_array = array(
            'count' => [$cancelled, $new, $completed],
            'center_text' => $center_text,
        );

        return $donut_data_array;
    }
```

And here is the ChartJS function:

```
ajaxGetPostMonthlyData: function () {
            //var urlPath =  'http://' + window.location.hostname + '/get-post-chart-data';
            //var urlPath =  'http://nipayandtuazon.com/get-rice-donut';
            //var urlPath =  'http://nipayandtuazon.com/get-rice-donut';
            var request = $.ajax( {
                method: 'GET',
                url: '/get-donut/1',
        } );
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WKwU.jpg

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

```
ajaxGetPostMonthlyData: function () {
        //var urlPath =  'http://' + window.location.hostname + '/get-post-chart-data';
        //var urlPath =  'http://nipayandtuazon.com/get-rice-donut';
        //var urlPath =  'http://nipayandtuazon.com/get-rice-donut';
        var request = $.ajax( {
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/get-donut/{{$id}}',
    } );
```

Now you can pass anything on $id dynamically. If you are doing it from the client side, You will need to pass a variable. FOr example you can get an element by id and get its value then put it there. Not sure if you are trying to achieve this in the front end using input boxes or from the server side.